# Error Class 'App\\Helpers\\SomeClass' not found in laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel-4

I had files project in directory main, but move part of the project to internal class how execute this code this return error

Class 'App\Helpers\SomeClass' not found in /var/www/html/myapp/your-project-name/app/views/tomi/index.php on line 14

```
    <?php
namespace App\Helpers;


class SomeClass
{
    public static function SomeMethod()
    {
      print "<font color=red>Dobrze</font>";
    }

    public static function SomeMethod2()
    {
      print "<font color=red>źle</font>";
    }
    public static function menu() {



    }
    public static function form(){

     Form::open(array('url' => '/','method' => 'get'));

print ("<div align=center>");
  Form::text('szukaj', Input::old('szukaj'));
print ("<br>");
 Form::submit('Szukaj!');
   Form::close();

    }

}

?>
```

Comment: Have you try with `composer dump` in the console.

Comment: I did and still the same.

Comment: can you paste your composer.json file